# Finding out an Objects class in Python

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I am trying to find out the class of an object in python and struggling. object.class returns an error. What is the best way to inquire as to an objects class? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

```
 obj.__class__
```

**Example:**

```
>>> class foo:
...     pass
... 
>>> bar = foo()
>>> bar.__class__ == foo
True
```

Comment: I like to use `type(obj)` better. Thought it won't work with Python 2's old-style classes, so your suggestion is more robust.